# WebStorm: NodeJS Process finished with exit code 0

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I am new to NodeJS, I have downloaded my project from github and installed all the required NodeJS modules. and know it just showing

**Webstorm console:**

> run app.js

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

and stops the application.

Why it is getting stop. I cannot access `localhost:3000`. Your guidance will be highly appreciated.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var session = require('express-session');
var index = require('./routes/index');
var login = require('./routes/login');
var logout = require('./routes/logout');
var contact = require('./routes/contact');
var signup = require('./routes/signup');

var app = express();

var connection = require('express-myconnection');
var mysql = require('mysql');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(session({
    secret: '123secret',
    proxy: true,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(
    connection(mysql, {

    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'proj',
    password: '123456',
    port: 3306, //port mysql
    database: 'projectnode'
}, 'request')
);

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /assets
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'assets', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/login', login);
app.post('/login', login);
app.post('/signup', signup);
app.get('/contact', contact);
app.post('/contact', contact);
app.get('/logout', logout);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Can you share app.js?

Comment: you running from webstrom run button ?

Comment: by right click on app.js file

Comment: This file doesn't actually do anything. You're not starting a server.

Comment: ok please give my any example URL so that i can learn. i am new to nodejs

Comment: var app = require(app.js); app.listen(port), sth like that, just start your app basically

Comment: where should i write this line ?

Comment: application is running even i am getting results line by line when trying to print console.here('this line working'); etc....

Comment: create a new project in webstrom thats all your new project is ready to run

Comment: i got the error: my file bin/www.js  is not calling ... please let me know how to call it like it is called when we create new node app

Comment: do u need project of webstorme?

Comment: lol :D i got the solution ... thanks alot.. for your time..! we are also from same country nice to meet you..

Comment: haahha u welcome nice to meet u ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I once had this problem before because the Webstorm console was executing `app.js` instead of `www`.

Just go to **Run/Debug Configurations** panel (You can access this from the **Navigation Bar**):

[image: Access Run/Debug Configurations from the Navigation Bar]

Navigate to your `app.js` **Configuration** tab and then change the path for the **JavaScript file** to your `www` file.

Comment: thanks for that. somehow (probably fat finger key mash related) i'd created another run config